# Were there additional written scrolls given by G-d to Moses?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, oral-torah, masechet-midot

[Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1081?lang=he), claims that there was an additional written scroll - [the Temple Scroll (?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Scroll) - given by G-d to Moses and passed on to all the following generations to Shlomo, mimicking the first lines of Avos:

> ... [**מגילת בית המקדש** מסרה הקב"ה [למשה
>   ...משה מסרה ליהושע 
>   ...יהושע לזקנים ... זקנים לנביאים... נביאים לדוד
>   ....עמד דוד ומסרה לשלמה בנו בעמידה

It seems that this Meggilah is completely unrelated to the Masechet Middos of the Shas that deals with the de-facto dimensions of the Second Temple.

I am confused: if it was in writing, why wasn't it a part of the [Written] Torah, if it was oral, how was it a scroll - how can it be written?

And were there claims for additional scrolls that Moses received from G-d?

Comment: "The Temple Scroll" is a name given by scholars to the document, not by the authors of the document. It has nothing to do with the מגילת בית המקדש of the Yalkut Shim'oni

Comment: @ba Very interesting, why would you say that? It seems to fit perfectly: WIKI says "שינויי לשון הכתוב לגוף ראשון, שלא יהיה ספק כי אלוהים אמר כתובים אלו, וכן היא מדגישה כי הדברים רק הועלו על הכתב בידי משה רבנו."

Comment: Speaking on behalf of God in first person is a literary device used by the Bible and also by the rabbis. My point is just that the name "Temple Scroll" is only a modern convention, so the fact that they are called by the same name is just a coincidence

Comment: There is also the ספר מלחמות ה mentioned in parshat chukat. However, I don't know of anyone who claims that that was authored by G-d.

Comment: @JoelK And whether it is or is not, how does it change anything in the question?

Comment: If it was written by G-d then it would be another example of a divine written text in Moses' possession

Comment: There are other "books" alluded to in the Torah, for example, in, I think, parshat Balak, there's a reference to the "Book of G-d's wars". Maybe this was an actual scroll given to Moshe that was eventually lost?